# Recurring Payment IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring

Quick question about the notify_url HTML variable (from PayPal Payments Standard).   I am specifying the URL as a variable that is sent to PayPal via a redirect URL for a recurring payment setup (all is working as expected when setting up the recurring payment).

But I am wondering, when PayPal goes to actually process a payment in the future (actual recurring payment), will it use the same URL for the IPN notification that was used during the recurring payment setup?

I have multiple IPN scripts, one for regular payments and one for recurring payments - I want to be sure that each future recurring payment uses a specific IPN script.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First, for the sake of terminology, if you're using HTML buttons then you're using Standard Subscriptions, not Recurring Payments.  Technically, they're the same thing, but Recurring Payments is API based and IPN data is different for Standard Subscriptions vs. Recurring Payments.  Just keep that in mind when searching for information about the two.

As for the IPN's, unfortunately, it will not continue to use that same URL.  You'll need to make sure that IPN is configured in the PayPal account profile in order for future transactions related to the profile to trigger IPN's.

This goes for both Standard Subscriptions and Recurring Payments API transactions.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Yes you are correct, I meant Standard Subscriptions.  So there is no way to specify which URL to use for Standard Subscriptions?

Comment: Well, yes, you do it from within your PayPal profile.  You can't do it from the notify_url parameter, though.  If I remember correctly the initial subscr_signup IPN would go to what you set in notify_url, but all future transactions for that profile would not be triggered unless that URL was configured in the profile.